# Зависание Ubuntu 18.04 при загрузке

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, asus

Сразу скажу, что являюсь новичком в использовании Linux. У меня возникла такая проблема, что иногда виснет система на том месте, где нужно выбрать профиль входа в систему. Перезагрузка помогает, но через какое-то время опять виснет на том же месте.
Системный раздел установлен на SSD, если это важно. Стоит Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, никакой другой системы не стоит. Ноутбук ASUS 556UQ.
Если нужны будут какие-то логи или информация, то опишите какие именно и как их получить.
UPD: добавил логи
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также должен добавить что у меня стоит в ноутбуке сломанная дискретная видеокарта, однако `lspci | grep VGA` видит только интегрированую. Но всё же, есть вероятность что в дискретке тоже может быть причина проблемы и таких логов?

Comment: сам GDM виснет и не даёт выбрать пользователя/ввести пароль? или как это выглядит?

Comment: во-первых установите (или удалите) проприетарный видео драйвер и проверьте разницу. во-вторых установите `gnome-logs`, посмотрите, какие там ошибки во вкладке "важные".

Comment: ну а вообще, как вариант для ленивых - можно удалить gdm и установить вместо него любой другой *dm. вот, например, инструкция по конфигурированию lightdm: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf намертво всё зависает, можно только перезагрузить.

Comment: nouveau удалите, это очень глючный хакерский драйвер

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf поприетарный видео драйвер у меня можно установить только на дискретную видеокарту, но ведь она нерабочая. Когда еще был установлен Windows 10, то при попытке включить видеокарту вылетал BSOD и приходилось её через безопасный режим отключать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог совет @PavelGridin, после удаления nouveau в логах больше не было огромного количества ошибок и система начала запускаться быстрее и без зависания.